# How to remove first line of element

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, ui-testing

Im having a small issue when writing my tests. Currently an element I am trying to use is returning me `Points:-` when I print it on the console. In the html its in the format `Points:` and on the next line `-`. How can I remove the "Points: " from this element so it only returns `-` and also assign the value `0` to it if its `-` (dash)?

My previous code is

```
Integer point_player = Integer.parseInt(points_player);
System.out.println(point_player);
```

And that used to only return a String from 0-9 which I could just convert to integer but now the `-`(dash) has been introduced.

Comment: Please attach html code snip of element

Comment: If you provide the HTML, we likely can come up with a locator that locates specifically the points without the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To strip a prefix, use `String.substring(index)`:

```
points_player = points_player.substring(7); // Strip "Points:"
```

Now spaces might be left:

```
points_player = points_player.trim(); // Strip whitespace
```

Lastly, you need to convert to int in the correct way:

```
int value;
if ("-".equals(points_player)) {
    value = 0; // No points, yet
} else {
    value = Integer.parseInt(points_player);
}

System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what are you looking after.then try this.

```
    String string = "Points:-";
    String[] s = string.split(":");
    String s1 = s[0] + ":"; // Points:
    String s2 = s[1]; // -
    System.out.println(s1); //
    System.out.println(s2);
```